# weight loss metabolism boost and muscle gain

Tags: weight-loss, metabolism, muscle-gain

It's been 2 years since I worked out I've gained a significant  amount of weight, approximately  60 pounds I weight 240 I'm 19, 5'9. The last time I worked out I max benched 2 plates and a 25, now I'm struggling with a 35. Along with that I've tried all diets imaginable but nothing I even went as far as fasting. Myetablolism is ridiculously  slow and I really want to get in shape and loose this fat bcs I know for a fact the muscle I used to have is gone. Any help with the weightless muscle gain and metabolism boost will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your metabolism, and it's not something you train. The difference between someone with a "slow" and a "fast" metabolism is very small.

**You need to diet properly.**

If you're gaining weight, or not losing weight, it's simply because you eat too much. Again, you can't train your metabolism to work faster. You have to control your caloric intake.

As far as weightless muscle gain goes, this is more likely to be doable if you're a beginner, and becomes harder to accomplish as you build more muscle.

I have a hard time taking you seriously when you say

> I've tried all diets imaginable but nothing

To anyone here, this is going to sound like crap. Fact of the matter is, diet is how you control your weight gain/loss. Working out simply controls how your body deals with the added/removed weight.

I suggest you try a [ketogenic diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketogenic_diet). Entering ketosis isn't the easiest feat, but if you do it, you'll lose weight at a pretty decent rate.

Comment: I've tried fasting, low carb diet, detox, and literally i barely eat I work two jobs to help provide for my family and i literally live on coffee and a meal a day. I just haven't gotten anywhere. I walk almost 5 miles easy everyday, I just don't know what to do anymore and my doctor is not helping he prescribed pills but I won't go down that route.

Comment: @AhmedAbdullah - Weight gain is one simple thing; you consume more calories than you spend. Start counting calories.

Comment: Even if you only have coffee and one meal a day, if it is of the wrong sort it can completely ruin the diet for the day. There are many fast food meals that can add up to be well over 2000 calories in one sitting.